# Is there a specific way of using pods or IBDesignables in iOS Frameworks?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ios-frameworks, ibdesignable

I am working on a framework project. I have added a custom view using IBDesignable in the framework (present within the framework under the same target). I am using the 'TinyConstraints' pod for simpler constraint codes.

When I am using the custom view in the storyboard within the framework, it is not working and gives the following error:

> error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for MyViewController (BYZ-38-t0r): dlopen(MyFramework.framework, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/TinyConstraints.framework/TinyConstraints
> Referenced from: MyFramework.framework
> Reason: image not found

I have tried a lot of solutions found in similar posts but nothing works for me:

- I tried the pod run path setup post-installation, but it still gave the same error.
- I tried clearing the derived data, cleaning the build folder and restarting XCode as well.

I have been struggling to get rid of it for hours. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is TinyConstraints a framework file?

Comment: If everything else false, consider adding TinyConstraints manually instead of using the Pod (some paraphrase of "If you can't win them join them")

Comment: Thanks, @ArikSegal!
I solved the issue by adding TinyConstraints files within the framework project.
Though this works well because of the fact that TinyConstraints has included an MIT license in all the files which allows me to use it openly. I would still like to know the right way to solve this problem of using pods.

Comment: A strange thing that I noticed is that when I don't even use the methods of TinyConstraints (or even add the import statement) and only add the pod, it still gives the same issue. I am guessing this is an issue between IBDesignables and pods working together.